# How do I get this bit of PHP to output in this table?

Tags: php, html

This is the code

```
for($r=1; $r<=10; $r++){
if($shirt_info[$r][0]!='Select One')
{
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Order $r: </div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Size: '.$shirt_info[$r][0].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Price: '.$shirt_info[$r][1].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Qty: '.$shirt_info[$r][2].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>SPE: '.$shirt_info[$r][5].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>LIA: '.$shirt_info[$r][6].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Vendor: '.$shirt_info[$r][7].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Style: '.$shirt_info[$r][8].'</div>';
    echo '<div class='shirtinfo'>Color: '.$shirt_info[$r][9].'</div>';
    echo '<div style='clear:both;'></div>';
}}
```

and this is the result http://www.redfivedesigns.com/screenshot2.jpg

Comment: That's invalid PHP syntax to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

From php manual:

> For information on how strings behave, especially with regard to usage
>   of single quotes, double quotes, and escape sequences, see the Strings
>   entry in the Types section of the manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
// Outputs: Arnold once said: "I'll be back"
echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"';
```

Comment: I did change them to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotes or use double quotes:

Escaping:

```
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Order $r: </div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Size: '.$shirt_info[$r][0].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Price: '.$shirt_info[$r][1].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Qty: '.$shirt_info[$r][2].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>SPE: '.$shirt_info[$r][5].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>LIA: '.$shirt_info[$r][6].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Vendor: '.$shirt_info[$r][7].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Style: '.$shirt_info[$r][8].'</div>';
echo '<div class=\'shirtinfo\'>Color: '.$shirt_info[$r][9].'</div>';
echo '<div style=\'clear:both;\'></div>';
```

Using double quotes:

```
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Order $r: </div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Size: '.$shirt_info[$r][0].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Price: '.$shirt_info[$r][1].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Qty: '.$shirt_info[$r][2].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">SPE: '.$shirt_info[$r][5].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">LIA: '.$shirt_info[$r][6].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Vendor: '.$shirt_info[$r][7].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Style: '.$shirt_info[$r][8].'</div>';
echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Color: '.$shirt_info[$r][9].'</div>';
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
```

Also, I think you mean `echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Order '.$r.': </div>';` instead of `echo '<div class="shirtinfo">Order $r: </div>';`